# VirtualBox Guest Additions causes problems with X server in Fedora 18. How to solve without reinstalling?

Tags: linux, fedora, x11, virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox (and it's Guest Additions), and after updating the kernel to the latest and also updating VB accordingly, I can not boot normally . (X server doesn't start, but I can login using Ctrl+Alt+F2)

I read in the last post [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=277055) that the problem is probably caused by graphical parts (OpenGL hardware 3D acceleration) of this Guest Addition.

Is there any way to fix the problem without reinstalling Fedora ?

Comment: How did you update VB and what graphics card/driver do you have?

Comment: @schaiba After updating linux kernel, you have to run a command to update VB to make it work on the new kernel. GraphicsCard: CPU's built-in Intel HD Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

you can do two things:

1.The first is to disabled 3D acceleration on the vm until it gets fixed.

1. What does the logs for the X server say? if X does not boot there will be a reason there, you can try to debug and maybe go further.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do that? (the first one)

Comment: check VM settings in vbox for the display. disable 3d acceleration